# Where is the Slingshot roadmap?

Tags: untagged

The other day I watched [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtPzNIlC-fA&t=1512s).

https://github.com/stellar/slingshot

I'm application engineer and  I'm interested in slingshot. I want to use slingshot in a Stellar service that I'm developing now.

So, I want to know the Slingshot roadmap. When do they release a testnet and livenet?